# Whitespace issue when positioning two centered images one on top of the other

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to position one image centered in the top of another, but the image on the top isn't exactly centered in the top/bottom and the another image doesn't have the same height of the , so when I use the same code twice it appears a white space between images.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swayziak/964FS/1/)

And the code:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="" class="link">
        <span><img src="" class="topImage"></span>
        <img src=""/>   
    </a>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <a href="" class="link">
        <span><img src="" class="topImage"></span>
        <img src=""/>   
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
} 

 .container a span {
   display: none;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.4);
   opacity: .95;
 }

.container a:hover span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

 .topImage {
    width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom:0; left: 0; right:0;
    margin: auto;
   }

  img {
      width: 100%;
  }
```

I want to center the image in the top and remove the whitespace between the images in the background.

Thanks.

Comment: Please proofread your question: it is quite vague at the moment.

Comment: First: Is the loading gif image correctly positioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whitespace between the images is due to the default `display` which is set out for the `img` tag, which is `inline-block`, change this to `block`

```
  img {
      display:block;
      width: 100%;
  }
```

see this at: http://jsfiddle.net/964FS/15/

Comment: Thanks now it works well. But I think the image of the top isn't exactly centered, right?

Comment: i checked chrome and ff, both the images are being rendered in the center, can you perhaps send me a screenshot?

Comment: I already checked out better and the image is centered. Probably it was an optical illusion or something. Thanks.